# Ordenando pela data quanto elas são do tipo string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, front-end

eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em angularJS a qual recebe o seguinte objeto de uma API:

```
pessoas = [
    { nome: 'Lucas', data: '2010-Fev-04'},
    { nome: 'Felipe', data: '1994-Dec-10'},
    { nome: 'Ana', data: '1994-Jun-21'},
    { nome: 'Carlos', data: '1991-Fev-20'}
];
```

Eu preciso ordenar a coluna pela data, mas ela vem em forma de string da API. Eu não consigo ver uma forma de ordenar as datas de forma correta já que eu não tenho como alterar o conteúdo desse objeto e tornar a data um timestamp.

Comment: A partir do momento que você recebe esse objeto da API, ele é apenas uma cópia dos dados originais e poderia ser manipulado na sua aplicação Angular. Não entendi a restrição que colocou, poderia dar mais contexto?

Comment: Oi Marcel. O problema é que com a data em forma de string, a ordenação não se dará de forma temporal. Por exemplo, 1994-Dec-10 seria menor que 1994-Jun-21. Eu pensei em criar um segundo objeto a partir do primeiro, usando o new Date pra mudar o formato, mas como o tamanho do objeto pode variar, eu não sei se isso seria a melhor opção

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma forma sem usar recursos adicionais. Irá gerar um novo array chamado `ordenados` com os objetos ordenados pela data usando `.sort()`. A lógica é converter as datas em objeto data válido. Com isso pode-se fazer uma comparação direta, verificando se uma é maior que a outra (veja explicações no código):

```js
function fData(i){
   
   // objeto para converter nomes em números dos meses
   var mes = {
      Jan: 0, Fev: 1, Mar: 2, Abr: 3, Mai: 4, Jun: 5,
      Jul: 6, Ago: 7, Set: 8, Out: 9, Nov: 10, Dez: 11
   }
   
   // converto a data recebida em array
   i = i.data.split("-");
   
   // converto os valores em objeto data
   var d = new Date(i[0],mes[i[1]],i[2]);
   
   // retorna o objeto
   return d;
   
}

pessoas = [
    { nome: 'Lucas', data: '2010-Fev-04'},
    { nome: 'Felipe', data: '1994-Dez-10'},
    { nome: 'Carlos', data: '1991-Fev-20'},
    { nome: 'Jose', data: '1994-Jun-21'},
    { nome: 'Maria', data: '1991-Fev-19'},
    { nome: 'João', data: '1984-Mar-01'}
];

var ordenados = pessoas.sort(function(a,b){

   // retorna os valores da função fData()
   // em formato de objeto de data
   a = fData(a);
   b = fData(b);
   
   // retorna primeiro o que for menor
   // caso queria inverter, basta trocar ">" por "<"
   return a > b;

});

console.log(ordenados);
```

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou bastante

Answer (score 5):

Com recurso ao momentjs para fazer o parsing das datas.
https://momentjs.com

As datas devem ter o mesmo idioma, no exemplo em causa Fev,Dez || Feb,Dec no teu caso estão misturadas.

```js
pessoas = [{
        nome: 'Lucas',
        data: '2010-Fev-04'
    },
    {
        nome: 'Felipe',
        data: '1994-Dez-10'
    },
    {
        nome: 'Ana',
        data: '1994-Jun-21'
    },
    {
        nome: 'Carlos',
        data: '1991-Fev-20'
    }
];


moment.locale('pt')

function comparar_datas(a, b) {
    d1 = moment(a.data, "YYYY-MMM-DD");
    d2 = moment(b.data, "YYYY-MMM-DD");
    if (d1.isAfter(d2)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (d1.isBefore(d2)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

pessoas.sort(comparar_datas);
console.log(pessoas)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```